# Android Invalid index 0, size is 0

Tags: java, android

I have an error coming up and it's saying it is in this method pointing at the address list. Does anyone has a suggestion why this is happening and the app crashes?

Appreciate it.

> 01-22 14:03:25.466 2271-2271/? E/AndroidRuntime:
> java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 0, size is 0

```
List<Address> addressList=null;

if (address!=null || !address.equals("")) {
    Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(getActivity());
    try {
        addressList = geocoder.getFromLocationName(address, 1);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
if (addressList != null){
    Address addresses = addressList.get(0);
    // my address lng and lgnt
    latLngOffers = new LatLng(addresses.getLatitude(), addresses.getLongitude());
    latLocation = addresses.getLatitude();
    longLocation = addresses.getLongitude();
    // Log.d("Offer address", String.valueOf(latLocation));

}
// latOffer=53.3399009;
// Log.d("my location inside", String.valueOf(latOffer));

DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("##.###");
df.setRoundingMode(RoundingMode.DOWN);
// System.out.println(df.format(latLocation));
Log.d("offer location", String.valueOf(df.format(longLocation)));
Log.d("my location inside", String.valueOf(df.format(longOffer)));

String loffer = df.format(latOffer);
String lonOffer = df.format(longOffer);
String llocation = df.format(latLocation);
String lngLocation = df.format(longLocation);
String lsearch = df.format(latSearch);
String lngsearch = df.format(longSearch);
```

Comment: The size is `0`, so you can't access any elements. The element at index `0` is only there if the size is `1` or greater.

Comment: This is more a java than an android problem. Not just check for addressList!=null put also for isEmpty()

Answer (score 0):

If there are no elements in a list or array, you can not retrieve the first (non-existing) element.

The valid indices are:

```
0 -> (number of elements - 1)
```

If there are no elements, there is no valid index.